# Is there a difference between "come" and "come out" in the sense of arriving at a place?

Tags: word-usage, difference

I have noticed that people, particularly Americans, sometimes say *come out* instead of *come* in the sense of arriving at a place. For example, in the 23rd episode of the fifth season of *Friends* Joey, who is in Las Vegas says to Chandler, who in New-York the following.

> Don't **come out** here!

Interestingly enough, I couldn't find any dictionary that defined *come out* as arriving somewhere.
Is *come out* used when talking about coming somewhere from a different city? If so, then is it totally synonymous with *come* in that sense?

Answer (score 1):

That combination isn't in a dictionary, because it's a verb followed by an adverb, not a single verb. It's a common usage meaning to come to a more or less distant place.

Here is a definition of "out" that applies:
[American Heritage Dictionary "out" adverb](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=out)
3.a. Away from a usual place: *stepped out for a drink of water; went out for the evening.*

Someone could speak of a distant place, saying "I'm going to **go** out there to visit a friend."

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Could you tell me if can just say "come" with the same meaning?

Comment: Yes, in that context, "Don't come here!" , with a little extra stress on "here" would have the same denotation, but it wouldn't be as specific to the sense of someone coming from a distant location coming to join another person already there..

Comment: I suspect it's _come / out here_ rather than _come out / here_.